# Are there disadvantages to using aluminum instead of malleable iron conduit bodies with galvanized rigid conduit?

Tags: electrical, conduit

I've noticed that aluminum conduit bodies for rigid conduit are cheaper than malleable iron. Are there disadvantages to using aluminum conduit bodies instead of malleable iron ones with galvanized rigid/IMC? I did find a comment on the Mike Holt forum which suggested that malleable iron was less likely to crack/fail under stress from an extra half turn of the conduit made in order to get fittings to face the right direction. I'm just dealing with 1/2 inch and 3/4 inch trade sizes here and yes I know that EMT is cheaper :)

Example only aluminum conduit body:
[image]

Example only malleable iron conduit body:
[image]

Comment: Dissimilar metal [corrosion](https://youtu.be/93OjIcpNuWY?t=247) if it's outdoors or wet.

Comment: Galvanized conduit is steel. Producing cast iron tubing with wall thickness as thin as 1/8 in. would be expensive. Are you talking about water piping ? Difficult to imagine plastic deformation of one half turn in steel or cast iron.

Comment: @blacksmith37 This is electrical conduit, "rigid" in this case and galvanized. Traditional conduit bodies have been galvanized (not sure if current "malleable" is the same thing), but cast(?) copper-free aluminum seems to be making inroads. Just wondering if there are downsides in using the cheaper aluminum bodies with my galvanized steel rigid conduit. Since it's indoors it sounds like galvanic corrosion is not something to worry about here.

Comment: I thought you meant the tubing , not the fittings. You are correct, corrosion will not be a problem as long as it is dry.